# How can I simplify this matrix algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How can I simplify the following matrix algebra?

$\theta^TA\theta - b^T(A^{-1})^TA\theta - \theta^TAA^{-1}b + b^T(A^{-1})^TAA^{-1}b$

where $\theta$ is a $p \times 1$ column vector, $A$ is a $p \times p$ matrix, and $b$ a $p \times 1$ vector. I know $AA^{-1} = I$ but I don't know what to do with the $(A^{-1})^TA$. I believe the answer should be $\theta^TA\theta - 2b^T\theta$ but my linear algebra is too rusty to get me there.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Do we know, by any chance, that $A$ is symmetric?

Comment: $A^{-1}$ is the variance of a normal distribution so yes I think $A$ would be symmetric?

Comment: If that's the case, we have $A^T = A$, so that a lot of this simplifies.  In particular, $A + A^T$ becomes $2A$.

Comment: ah that's very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a helpful trick: make the substitution $y = A^{-1}b$, and we can rewrite the expression as
$$
\theta^TA\theta - y^TA \theta - \theta^T A y + y^TAy
$$
In fact, we can rewrite the above as $(\theta - y)^TA(\theta - y)$, which I would claim is a simpler form.

---

That doesn't seem to be the simplification you're looking for, so here's another: Note that $b^T[A^{-1}]^TA \theta$ is a number, so it is equal to its *transpose*, namely $\theta^TA^TA^{-1}b$.  So, we can simplify the above as
$$
\theta^TA\theta - \theta^TA^TA^{-1}b - \theta^TAA^{-1}b + b^T[A^{-1}]^Tb = \\
\theta^TA\theta - \theta^T[A + A^T]A^{-1}b + [b^T[A^{-1}]^Tb]^T =\\
\theta^TA\theta - \theta^T[A + A^T]A^{-1}b + b^TA^{-1}b
$$
That's about the best we can do.